# Docker: как изменить адрес по умолчанию именованного тома?

Tags: linux, веб-сервер, администрирование, docker, docker-compose

В корне проекта лежит файл *docker-compose.yum*:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
    db:
        container_name: my_db
        image: mysql
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - "mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345
            MYSQL_DATABASE: test
            MYSQL_USER: vlad
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 12345

volumes:
    mysql:
```

После *docker-compose up -d --build* на хосте создается соответствующий том в каталоге: */var/lib/docker/volumes/*

Вопрос:
Как изменить этот адрес по умолчанию на свой?
Т.е. я хочу чтобы этот том создавался не по адресу */var/lib/docker/volumes/* , а по адресу, например, */home/vlad/my_project/mysql*. Хочу хранить все файлы проекта в одном месте!

Answer (score 0):

Для именованного тома - никак, но вместо тома вы можете смонтировать произвольную директорию на хосте:

```
volumes:
  - /home/etki/Workspace/playground/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

При этом имейте в виду, что докер действует от пользователя root, и все созданные файлы и директории будут принадлежать ему.